# Android - How to find my rooted path

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova

I am creating a new app using phonegap (html and javascript) and am using an SQLite database. Due to phonegap limitations and my need for a dynamic database I am following these steps:

1 - creating an external database
2 - exporting this with the .apk file
3 - on app load I replace the phonegap database with my database

The issue I am having here is working out whether 'LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT' or TEMPORARY. It looks like it is persistent. However, I am not sure how I can root my device allowing me to access and replace the database within the relevnt 'LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT' section.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default your SQlite database is created at:

```
/data/data/Your Package/databases/your database
```

[For using already created database see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9109728/265167).

Comment: Does this mean it the database is stored in the same path for both emulation and on the actual device after app download. As for the link to use already created database is not relevent as I cannot use Java, due to my app being compiled using phonegap. Thanks

Comment: do you know what the file path is got all my other html pages? Tried - file:///store/home/user/RANDOMAPPNAME/www/